# Convert TensorFlow Graph from PB to float16 operations

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a frozen graph, PB file which i import to TensorFlow, at the moment all the data types and operations are done in float32, how can i convert everything to float16 instead, even the operations such as multiply, convolutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [quantization tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.7/performance/quantization) by Tensorflow: it does exactly this, along with many more (optional) optimizations to further reduce the model's size and increase its inference-time speed.